# returning cast subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a superclass `Entity` and there are subclasses like `Post`, `Comment` etc.

I want to add to `Entity` a generic method that will return a cast list in the subclasses. So for example I want to call this:

```
List<Post> posts = Post.findAll();
```

I have tried this:

```
public class Entity {
    public static List<?> findAll() {
        return ???;
    }
}
```

But I think the syntax is not what I am after because when I do this:

```
for(Post post : Post.findAll()) {

}
```

It gives the error `Type mismatch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want a generic method and not a generic class, you may try something like:

```
public class Entity {
    static <T extends Entity> List<T> findAll(Class<T> type){
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        //populate your list  

        return list;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:
    `List<Post> list = Entity.findAll(Post.class);`

Comment: probably the closest I can get to what I wanted

Comment: @Paul, glad to help. You might consider marking it as an answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Entity<T> {
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return ???;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Post extends Entity<Post> {
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to a non-static type in the line: public static List<T> findAll()

Comment: ok, but it is no longer static. I guess you can't do this in java

Comment: Ses the other answer if you want it static